# Calling a function within function does not work as expected?

Tags: python, list, function, maze

I'm designing a maze generator in python and have various functions for different steps of the process. (I know the code can most definitely be improved but I'm just looking for an answer to my problem first before I work on optimizing it)

the first function generates a base maze in the form of a 2D list and works as expected:

```
def base_maze(dimension):
    num_rows = int((2 * dimension[1]) + 1)          #number of rows / columns
    num_columns = int((2 * dimension[0]) + 1)       #from tuple input

    zero_row = []                                   #initialise a row of 0s
    for i in range(num_columns):
        zero_row.append(0)

    norm_row = []                                   #initialise a row of
    for i in range(num_columns // 2):               #alternating 0s and 1s
        norm_row.extend([0,1])
    norm_row.append(0)

    maze = []                                       #initialise maze
                                                    #(combination of zero rows 
    for i in range(num_rows  // 2):                 # and normal rows)
        maze.append(zero_row)
        maze.append(norm_row)
    maze.append(zero_row)

    return maze
```

Another function gets the neighbors of the selected cell, and also works as expected:

```
def get_neighbours(cell, dimension):

    y = cell[0]                                     #set x/y values
    max_y = dimension[0] - 1                        #for reference

    x = cell[1]
    max_x = dimension[1] - 1

    n = (x, y-1)                                    #calculate adjacent
    e = (x+1, y)                                    #coordinates
    s = (x, y+1)
    w = (x-1, y)

    if y > max_y or y < 0 or x > max_x or x < 0:        #check if x/y
        raise IndexError("Cell is out of maze bounds")  #in bounds

    neighbours = []

    if y > 0:                                       #add cells to list
        neighbours.append(n)                        #if they're valid
    if x < max_x:                                   #cells inside maze
        neighbours.append(e)
    if y < max_y:                                   
        neighbours.append(s)
    if x > 0:                                       
        neighbours.append(w)

    return neighbours
```

the next function removes the wall between two given cells:

```
def remove_wall(maze, cellA, cellB):

    dimension = []
    x_dim = int(((len(maze[0]) - 1) / 2))           #calc the dimensions
    y_dim = int(((len(maze) - 1) / 2))              #of maze matrix (x,y)
    dimension.append(x_dim)
    dimension.append(y_dim)

    A_loc = maze[2*cellA[1]-1][2*cellA[0]-1]
    B_loc = maze[2*cellB[1]-1][2*cellB[0]-1]

    if cellB in get_neighbours(cellA, dimension):   #if cell B is a neighbour

        if cellA[0] == cellB[0] and cellA[1] < cellB[1]:            #if the x pos of A is equal
            adj_wall = maze[(2*cellA[0]+1)][2*cellA[1]+1+1] = 1     #to x pos of cell B and the y pos
                                                                    #of A is less than B (A is below B)
        elif cellA[0] == cellB[0] and cellA[1] > cellB[1]:          #the adjacent wall is set to 1 (removed)
            adj_wall = maze[(2*cellA[0]+1)][2*cellA[1]+1-1] = 1
                                                                    #same is done for all other directions
        if cellA[1] == cellB[1] and cellA[0] < cellB[0]:
            adj_wall = maze[(2*cellA[0]+1)+1][(2*cellA[1]+1)] = 1

        elif cellA[1] == cellB[1] and cellA[0] > cellB[0]:
            adj_wall = maze[(2*cellA[0]+1-1)][(2*cellA[1]+1)] = 1

        return maze
```

yet when I try to put these functions together into one final function to build the maze, they do not work as they work on their own, for example:

```
def test():
    maze1 = base_maze([3,3])
    maze2 = [[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]

    if maze1 == maze2:
        print("they are exactly the same")
    else:
        print("WHY ARE THEY DIFFERENT???")

    remove_wall(maze1,(0,0),(0,1))
    remove_wall(maze2,(0,0),(0,1))
```

these will produce different results despite the input being exactly the same?:

```
test()
they are exactly the same
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
[[0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], [0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0], [0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in your `base_maze` function, where you first create two types of row:

```
zero_row = []                                   #initialise a row of 0s
for i in range(num_columns):
    zero_row.append(0)

norm_row = []                                   #initialise a row of
for i in range(num_columns // 2):               #alternating 0s and 1s
    norm_row.extend([0,1])
norm_row.append(0)
```

This is fine so far and works as expected, however when you build the maze from there

```
for i in range(num_rows  // 2):                 # and normal rows)
    maze.append(zero_row)
    maze.append(norm_row)
maze.append(zero_row)
```

You are filling up the maze list with multiple instances of the same list. This means if you modify row 0 of the maze, row 2 & 4 will also be affected. To illustrate:

```
>>> def print_maze(maze):
...     print('\n'.join(' '.join(str(x) for x in row) for row in maze))
... 
>>> print_maze(maze)
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0
0 0 0 0 0
>>> maze[0][0] = 3
>>> print_maze(maze)
3 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0
3 0 0 0 0
0 1 0 1 0
3 0 0 0 0
```

Note that rows 0, 2, & 4 have all changed. This is because `maze[0]` is the same `zero_row` instance as `maze[2]` and `maze[4]`.

Instead, when you create the maze you want to use a *copy* of the row lists. This can be done easily in Python using the following slicing notation

```
for i in range(num_rows  // 2):
    maze.append(zero_row[:]) # note the [:] syntax for copying a list
    maze.append(norm_row[:])
maze.append(zero_row[:])
```

Comment: Ah! that makes so much sense thank you, @Peter Gibson. This works fine now and I understand the error. Could you please explain how the notation of [:] creates a copy? (I assume it's some weird python quirk?)

Comment: @JakePhillips It's explained well here http://henry.precheur.org/python/copy_list